# Filtering where the observed process has noise coefficient depending on state

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-filtering

In continuous-time, the state process is assumed to follow
$$dX_t = f(X_t, t)dt + g(X_t, t)dW^1_t$$
and the observation process is usually assumed to follow something like
$$dZ_t = h(X_t, t)dt + dW^2_t.$$
I would like to find any theory about when the observation process instead follows
$$dZ_t = h(X_t, t)dt + \sigma(X_t, t)dW^2_t.$$
First post here, thanks in advance.